# How to align ag-grid table to the center of the sceen

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am new to Ag-Grid Angular, I have created the agGrid table and set width: 800px and height: 500px, but the table is aligned in the left side. Can anyone tell me how to center align tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin: auto` in `style` attribute of `ag-grid-angular`.

```html
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 200px; margin: auto;" class="ag-theme-alpine" [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```